# Selenium reply button not working

Tags: python, selenium

Good evening.  I'm working on an automated craigslist response program and I'm in need of someone to explain to me why when I get to click on the "reply", & the email clients come up, it doesn't click on them.  I've tried every method and find by element combo, to no avail.  I'm sure it's something that I'm overlooking in my code.  thanks in advance

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
def Job():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("http://charlotte.craigslist.org/sad/5838008849.html")
    assert "02 Nissan Xterra - $3000 (Matthews)" in driver.title
    assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
    #elem3.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("reply_button").click()
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("reply-emails").click()
    car = driver.find_element_by_link_text("mail.live.com").text
    message = "Hi, my name is" + name + " and" + car
Job()
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.  However, I'm now being presented with both Gmail and Hotmail user logins.  I can't seem to find the element id tags, nor understand how you were able to retrieve it from the last question.  And reference material I'll be glad to look over, as I read the selenium doc and still not sure why it's not working...

Comment: I think the problem is because it's opening in another tab.

Comment: I verified it's because it's not looking to the new tab, by using the old title for the assert, and it didn't error on that line like before with the assert on the title to the new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use another locators as you're trying to handle not clickable elements. Try following:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("replylink").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class=\"reply-email gmail\"]").click()
```

Comment: Thank you, I commented out the first line, and only used the 2nd, but it's working now with the correct id, thanks again...